# Интеграционные тесты с TestContainers mvn test

Tags: java, maven, юнит-тесты, junit

Ситуация следующая:
Написал интеграционные тесты, используя testcontainers. Все работает, если локально запускать тесты как Run Configuration, но mvn test падает, из-за того, что не может законнектиться к контейнеру

### BaseIntergrationTest

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = BaseIntegrationTest.Initializer.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Testcontainers
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {

  @Container
  public static final MySQLContainer container = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:5.7"));

  static {
    container.withDatabaseName("recruitment_test_db")
        .withUsername("test")
        .withPassword("pwd")
        .withInitScript("init-test.sql");
    container.start();
  }

  static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize( ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      System.out.println(container.getJdbcUrl());
      TestPropertyValues.of("spring.datasource.url=" + container.getJdbcUrl(),
          "spring.datasource.username=" + container.getUsername(),
          "spring.datasource.port" + container.getFirstMappedPort(),
          "spring.datasource.password=" + container.getPassword()).applyTo(applicationContext);
    }

  }
}
```

### RecruitmentServiceTest

```
class RecruitmentServiceImplTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired
  RecruitmentRepository repository;
  @Autowired
  RecruitmentMapper mapper;
  @Autowired
  private RecruitmentService service;

  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() {
    repository.deleteAll();
  }

  @DisplayName("Successful getting actual recruitment")
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource(
      "com.practice.recruitmentservice.provider.RecruitmentArgumentProvider#provideCurrentDateRecruitments"
  )
  void getSuccessful(Recruitment recruitment) {
    Long id = repository.save(recruitment).getId();
    RecruitmentDto expect = mapper.toDto(recruitment);
    RecruitmentDto actual = service.get(id);

    assertAll(
        () -> assertNotNull(actual),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getStartDate(), actual.getStartDate()),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getEndDate(), actual.getEndDate())
    );
  }

  @DisplayName("Successful getting actual recruitment")
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("com.practice.recruitmentservice.provider.RecruitmentArgumentProvider#provideCurrentDateRecruitments")
  void getActualSuccessful(Recruitment recruitment) {
    repository.save(recruitment);
    RecruitmentDto expect = mapper.toDto(recruitment);
    RecruitmentDto actual = service.getActual();

    assertAll(
        () -> assertNotNull(actual),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getStartDate(), actual.getStartDate()),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getEndDate(), actual.getEndDate())
    );
  }

  @DisplayName("Failed getting actual recruitment")
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("com.practice.recruitmentservice.provider.RecruitmentArgumentProvider#provideNotCurrentDateRecruitments")
  void getActualFailed(Recruitment recruitment) {
    repository.save(recruitment);

    RecruitmentDto actual = service.getActual();

    assertNull(actual);
  }

  @DisplayName("Successful creating recruitment")
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("com.practice.recruitmentservice.provider.RecruitmentArgumentProvider#provideCurrentDateRecruitments")
  void createSuccessful(Recruitment recruitment) {
    RecruitmentDto expect = mapper.toDto(recruitment);
    RecruitmentDto actual = service.create(expect);

    assertAll(
        () -> assertNotNull(actual),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getStartDate(), actual.getStartDate()),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getEndDate(), actual.getEndDate())
    );
  }

  @DisplayName("Failed creating recruitment: empty dto")
  @Test
  void createFailed_emptyDto() {
    //fixme
    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> service.create(RecruitmentDto.builder().build()));
  }

  @DisplayName("Successful update recruitment")
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("com.practice.recruitmentservice.provider.RecruitmentArgumentProvider#provideUpdatedCurrentDateRecruitments")
  void updateSuccessful(Map<String, Recruitment> recruitment) {
    Long id = repository.save(recruitment.get("initial")).getId();

    RecruitmentDto expect = mapper.toDto(recruitment.get("updated"));
    RecruitmentDto actual = service.update(id, expect);

    assertAll(
        () -> assertNotNull(actual),
        () -> assertEquals(id, actual.getId()),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getStartDate(), actual.getStartDate()),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getEndDate(), actual.getEndDate())
    );
  }

  @DisplayName("Failed updating recruitment: not found")
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("com.practice.recruitmentservice.provider.RecruitmentArgumentProvider#provideCurrentDateRecruitments")
  void updateFailed_notFound(Recruitment recruitment) {

    assertThrows(EntityNotFoundException.class, () -> service.update(recruitment.getId(),mapper.toDto(recruitment)));
  }

  @DisplayName("Success deleting recruitment")
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("com.practice.recruitmentservice.provider.RecruitmentArgumentProvider#provideCurrentDateRecruitments")
  void deleteSuccessful(Recruitment recruitment) {
    Long id = repository.save(recruitment).getId();

    RecruitmentDto expect = mapper.toDto(recruitment);
    RecruitmentDto actual = service.delete(id);

    assertAll(
        () -> assertNotNull(actual),
        () -> assertEquals(id, actual.getId()),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getStartDate(), actual.getStartDate()),
        () -> assertEquals(expect.getEndDate(), actual.getEndDate())
    );
  }

  @DisplayName("Failed deleting recruitment: not found")
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("com.practice.recruitmentservice.provider.RecruitmentArgumentProvider#provideCurrentDateRecruitments")
  void deleteFailed_notFound(Recruitment recruitment) {

    assertThrows(EntityNotFoundException.class, () -> service.delete(recruitment.getId()));
  }


}
```

### stack trace

```
2021-04-05 13:40:14.323  INFO 6399 --- [           main]  [mysql:5.7]                           : Creating container for image: mysql:5.7
2021-04-05 13:40:14.648  INFO 6399 --- [           main]  [mysql:5.7]                           : Starting container with ID: 8042827ce69afdae999803aacda579e36c8f990ebfe001083829e716e0bd84c2
2021-04-05 13:40:15.188  INFO 6399 --- [           main]  [mysql:5.7]                           : Container mysql:5.7 is starting: 8042827ce69afdae999803aacda579e36c8f990ebfe001083829e716e0bd84c2
2021-04-05 13:40:15.195  INFO 6399 --- [           main]  [mysql:5.7]                           : Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mysql://localhost:49157/recruitment_test_db using query 'SELECT 1'
2021-04-05 13:40:27.661  INFO 6399 --- [           main]  [mysql:5.7]                           : Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:49157/recruitment_test_db)
2021-04-05 13:40:27.663  INFO 6399 --- [           main]  [mysql:5.7]                           : Container mysql:5.7 started in PT13.339722S
2021-04-05 13:40:27.663  INFO 6399 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils       : Executing database script from init-test.sql
2021-04-05 13:40:27.817  INFO 6399 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils       : Executed database script from init-test.sql in 154 ms.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.835  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@57b2e99 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.838  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@316245b6 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.840  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@6d31bae5 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.841  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3fd2dbe2 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.843  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@55f2a26d (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.845  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@761e1290 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.846  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@16987824 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.850  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3f3cacde (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.860  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7f1d809e (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:40:27.862  WARN 6399 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7991877f (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-04-05 13:41:27.846  WARN 6399 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2021-04-05 13:41:27.846 ERROR 6399 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
2021-04-05 13:41:27.846 ERROR 6399 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел способ.
Достаточно было написать кастомный `Extention`, в котором переопределить метод `beforeAll` и создать там контейнер, а стоп контейнера оставить на Garbage Collector